# Vertical ScrollView inside vertical ViewPager2 not working Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have a basic `ViewPager2` in vertical orientation composed by 2 `Fragments`.

Inside the `Fragment` 2 I have a vertical `ScrollView`.

Both vertical scrolling are in conflicts and it's not working properly. I know there is a lot of similar problem but everything I found and tried failed.

I'm looking for a solution which will handle both touch event.

Any code example or lead thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve my problem by writing my custom scroll view to handle both vertical scrolling :

```
public class CustomScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

    public CustomScrollView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomScrollView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomScrollView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    float startY, dy;

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
        if (scrollY > 15) { // 10 - 15 -> avoid fake mouv
            viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                startY = ev.getRawY();
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startY = ev.getRawY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                dy = ev.getRawY() - startY;
                if (dy > -5 && dy < 70) { // range tested on 5 devices but can be modified
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```